# in java the after timer.cancel(), got exctpion

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Trying do some debouncing, the use case is that client may send multiple requests to server in short interval unnecessarily. The requests are all the same but response is different at the time of the server processing, so the last response is the one to use.

With following code if do not always create a new timer, after timer.cancel(), the timer.schedule() will crash with `"Timer already cancelled."`.

Can't the timer be reused?

Is there better way to do the debouncing without using timer?

```
private Timer debouncerTimer = new Timer();
synchronized void debounceRequest() {
       
        debouncerTimer.cancel();

        //debouncerTimer = new Timer(); //<== without this one it crashes with IllegalStateException("Timer already cancelled.")

        debouncerTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
                doSendRequest();
            }
        }, 150);
    }
```

Comment: The [documentation of `Timer` clearly says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html): "*Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals.*" Thus re-using is not in-scope and thus not possible.

Comment: You could use a ScheduledExecutorService. With that you could use the scheduleWithFixedDelay method to schedule a task with a fixed delay between the end of the previous task and the start of the next task.

Comment: Thank you guys. So in this case a new timer has to be created. Anyone cares about putting in an answer? I could approve it.

Answer (score 1):

> A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a
> background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or
> for repeated execution at regular intervals.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html

Here is an example using ScheduledExecutorService that could work:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService debouncer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledRequest;

synchronized void debounceRequest() {
    if (scheduledRequest != null) {
        scheduledRequest.cancel(false);
    }
    scheduledRequest = debouncer.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::doSendRequest, 0, 150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private void doSendRequest() {
    //Send request stuff here
}
```

Comment: -> `With flowing code if do not always create a new timer, after timer.cancel(), the timer.schedule() will crash with "Timer already cancelled.".`

The timer can not be executed again after `cancel()` has been called. It needs to be initialized again since it is meant for a one time execution. `...Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution...`